# Web3.js - OPTIONS http://localhost:8545/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, web3js

I am trying to configure web3.js for a website. I wish to authenticate using Ethereum.

I am getting the following error:

```
web3-light.js:4327 OPTIONS http://localhost:8545/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
HttpProvider.send   @   web3-light.js:4327
RequestManager.send @   web3-light.js:6334
get @   web3-light.js:6237
watchBalance    @   test.php:17
onclick @   test.php:31
```

Comment: Edited to make clear what was the error and what wasn't. This isn't my area but I suspect this question will need more detail and a better title to be answered correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You connect to localhost provider of ethereum node. Make sure that you use right provider, for example, infura.io

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

<script>
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
  } else {
    // Set the provider you want from Web3.providers
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io"))
  }
</script>
```